# Are there tools for viewing logs with rich data?

Tags: logs, log-analysis

I am new to the world of logging. I see that loggers (e.g. `sl4j` for Java or `winston` for JavaScript) support several "transports" that allow them to store the logs in files in various formats.

At first glance, I thought that this is to perhaps enable some standard log viewing tools to parse the logs.

I was expecting features offered by the browser console which I often use for viewing logs. It offers:

#### 1 Inspection of rich json objects

[image]

You can expand the object to view what you need, so the full json representation of the object doesn't clutter your screen:

[image]

#### 2 Filtering of logs

e.g. here I've filtered in only messages with `[tag]` in their text

[image]

---

I think there must be log viewing tools which offer these features, but I cannot find any (perhaps I'm not searching with the right terms). Most things I was able to find seem to be for a different purpose (like some kind of metrics, or knowing about health of a distributed cluster) and I'm not sure if they also support this basic log viewing case.

Are there such tools? If there are, are they tied to a particular language or only to a particular log format?

Comment: What about the [syslog-ng](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog-ng) ecosystem? It's a very old project, no longer preferred by the major Linux distributions. But I think the log file formats were more flexible, and there should exist some tools to parse these JSON- or XML-based log file formats.

Comment: @knb what's the log viewer called in that ecosystem? I think the trouble I'm having navigating all this log management software is that they offer quite a lot (computing metrics, logs from multiple sources, etc) and I'm not able to find enough information on what I'm looking for (a GUI for manually viewing and filtering logs as described in the question)